# sqrt(double) c++ not working

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    int i;
    int is_prime = true;

    cout << "Upisite broj i pritisnite Enter";
    cin >> n;
    i = 2;

    while (i <= sqrt(double n))
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
            ;
        is_prime = false;
        i++;
    }

    if (is_prime)
        cout << "Broj je prost";
    else
        cout << "broj nije prost";

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: problem:sqrt(double n) c++ does not compile i use dev-c++

Comment: `(double)`,  `sqrt((double)n)`.

Comment: also `if (n % i == 0);` should not have a semicolon there

Comment: even if i use sqrt((double)n) it does not work

Comment: What is `sqrt(double n)` supposed to do?

Comment: By the book that i bought this code should tell you if number that you typed is Prime number

Comment: Off topic: @Matija  I have formatted the code to expose the next bit of nastiness you will face.

Comment: Off topic: You aren't calling `sqrt` You are calling `std::sqrt`. Plan accordingly.

Comment: Off topic: after fixing up the syntax error, `while (i <= sqrt(n))` will keep calculate the square root of n for every iteration of the loop. The  square root of n will not change. Instead, compute the square root above the loop and store the value. Then use the value in the test. eg: `double sqrtn = sqrt(n); while (i <= sqrtn)`

Comment: Off topic: [read up on Eratosthenes's Seive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: By the way: the test `if (i*i <= n)` is exactly equivalent, but it requires no floating point conversion, no imprecision, and no function calls; and is almost certainly much faster.

Answer (score 1):

`sqrt(double n)` is a function prototype (almost; needs a return type).

You mean either `sqrt (double (n))` or `sqrt ((double) n)`.

Comment: Consider whether the information you provide is sufficient for people here to solve your problem.  Where exactly did you try `sqrt (double (n))`?  What did your code look like then?  What did it do instead of working?  If it was a compile-time error, what was the error?  If it was a run-time error, what was that?  Or was it just that you got the wrong answer?  The less information you give...

Comment: ... the harder it is to help you.  Tell all.  We may be able to see the problem if we can _see_ the problem.  It may _seem_ easier to say nothing but "it's not working," but since you don't get your answer that way, it's really _more_ work than giving details.